# Swift undeclared type and build settings

Tags: xcode, swift2

Error: Use of undeclared type CalendarViewDelegate

in ViewController.Swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CalendarViewDelegate
```

but i have the CalendarViewDelegate in CalendarKit\CalendarView.swift

```
protocol CalendarViewDelegate: class { ... }

class calendarView: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource ...
```

All the classes and protocols exist.. but they're not being loaded in the path. Im not familiar enough with Xcode, so where am i missing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put following statement in your `ViewController.Swift`

```
import calendarView
```

**Edit:**

Please ensure to set `Library Search Path` correctly in your target' build settings like this. Path should be relative to your .xcodeproj file.

[image]

Comment: Doing that gives me the error No such module calendarView

Comment: No such module calendarView. I must not have a path set or something. All of the calendar files are in a sub folder called CalendarKit

Comment: So i did that and its still not working. i know this has to be simple... and I'm probably staring right at it

Comment: Restarted and opened again after updating search path.. it works now

Comment: Thank you for the update. I was doing more research why it didn't work :). Glad it helped!